# How to change the line style in quiver3 plot, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, styles, line

I cannot figure out how to change the line style in a `quiver3` plot.
I want to change some of the lines to dashed and keep the others solid.
Suggestions would be helpful.
I have already tried:

```
 quiver3(0,0,0,a(1),a(2),a(3),'LineStyle','solid');
 hold on;    
 quiver3(0,0,0,b(1),b(2),b(3),'LineStyle','solid');
 hold on;    
 quiver3(0,0,0,c(1),c(2),c(3),'LineStyle','dashed');
```

and quite a few other things.
I'm new to matlab so go easy on me. please.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `LineStyle` property after you've created the plot object

```
h = quiver3((0,0,0,a(1),a(2),a(3));
set(h, 'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'r');
```